# Generate an optimized website

Tags: php, javascript, html

is there any tools that takes as input : html,javascript,css,php files (a web site files)
and generate a php file that when its run it optimale/fast/only needed stuff ...
or at least something that aproches that?

Comment: This is one of the reasons why using alternative to PHP, like FastCGI programs (coded in C++ ...), http://opalang.org/ or http://ocsigen.org/ make sense

Answer (score 3):

Even if this question could generate good feedback. It's not a good SO question. It's too broad and there's no single correct answer. Sounds like you're asking for a magic trick that will do your job for you, sorry to be rude.

If you want help optimizing your website, use http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/ , it'll analyze your website and show you things you could do to optimize it http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html, such as:

- Minimize HTTP Requests
- Use a Content Delivery Network
- Avoid empty src or href
- Add an Expires or a Cache-Control Header
- Gzip Components
- Put StyleSheets at the Top
- Put Scripts at the Bottom
- Avoid CSS Expressions
- Make JavaScript and CSS External
- Reduce DNS Lookups
- Minify JavaScript and CSS
- Avoid Redirects
- Remove Duplicate Scripts
- Configure ETags
- Make AJAX Cacheable
- Use GET for AJAX Requests
- Reduce the Number of DOM Elements
- No 404s
- Reduce Cookie Size
- Use Cookie-Free Domains for Components
- Avoid Filters
- Do Not Scale Images in HTML
- Make favicon.ico Small and Cacheable

Answer (score 2):

Considering that there is no way to logically associate what PHP and HTML (never mind CSS and JavaScript) are doing across files, the short answer is no.

However, you can optimize JavaScript using something such as the Google Closure compiler.

Answer (score 1):

At least you attempted to define "optimized". I hope that this question doesn't get closed. I would like to see what answers come up as one can always learn something new. However, there is an awful lot to optimizing.

Look into caching - which has nothing to do with the HTML which your PHP will produce. Look at JS & CSS compression (even JPEG reduction).

Be aware that different visitors see a different site (I am currently struggling with Drupal which is quite good at speeding things up for non-registered visitors, but that is not so easy for registered users, for each of whom a different page might need (time) to generated).

Look at things like Yslow, but remember that they can only apply to HML / CSS / JS – and not to PHP – maybe you are spending a lot of time in database access, so profile that.

In short, how long your piece of string is depends upon the characteristics of your piece of string.

I predict this question will be quickly closed (as is so sadly the trend these days (when I was a lad, all of this was fields and trees),  or will go on to be a several k-view classic.